# How to get quantity of products sold?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, collection, product-collection

I need to get the quantity of products sold on my report module.
Actually I'm only getting the ordered quantity, but I need to get the quantity of all finished orders.

Here is my actual code:

```
public function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addOrderedQty();

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Name),
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'name'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Quantity Sold'),
        'type' => 'number',
        'index' => 'ordered_qty'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

How can I get the desired result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me.

```
public function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addOrderedQty();

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => 'Name', // Single quote missing
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'name'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
        'header' => 'Quantity Sold',
        'type' => 'text',
        'index' => 'ordered_qty'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

I have removed the $this->_getHelper().

Comment: The problem with this code is that I get the ordered quantity, but I need the quantity of the ordered ones that have been paid(I'm actually trying to get now the invoiced quantity, but for no avail)

Comment: Then you need to modify the code and get collection of invoiced qty from invoice item table.

Comment: I tried that, but the invoiced quantity that appeared was inconsistent, can you give me a working example?